# How to make code for finding links in a massive .txt file for python faster?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Heres my code for finding a random link in a text file

```
@client.command(aliases=["randfile","randvideo","randlink"])
async def randimage(ctx):
    member=ctx.author
    newlinetosend=""
    attempts = 1
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('<:alive:709318738024857662>')
    line = random.choice(open('FullLogs.txt',encoding='ANSI').readlines())
    while "https://" not in line:
        line = random.choice(open('FullLogs.txt',encoding='ANSI').readlines())
        print(f"struggle tweets {attempts}")
        attempts = attempts+1
        if attempts==20:
            await ctx.send("bruh hold on this is taking a fat minute")
        if attempts==50:
            await ctx.send("I hate it here its taking sooo long")
        if attempts==100:
            await ctx.send("<:alive:709318738024857662>Everything is pain<:alive:709318738024857662>")
        if attempts==200:
            await ctx.send("smh you suck<:alive:709318738024857662><:alive:709318738024857662><:alive:709318738024857662>")
    linetosend = (re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", line).group("url"))
    #if linetosend[-1] == ']':
    if 'discordapp' or 'twitter' in linetosend:
        newlinetosend = linetosend.replace("]","")
        newlinetosend = newlinetosend.replace("'","")
        newlinetosend = newlinetosend.replace(">","")
    else:
        newlinetosend = linetosend
    print(newlinetosend)
    print(linetosend)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('<:ohgod:710655825261363240>')
    await ctx.send(f"{newlinetosend}")
```

This is triggered by doing the >randimage command
Currently it works perfectly although I was wondering if there would be a way to speed up the process. It is very slow.

Comment: Your question is vague and opinionated. Needs more focus.

Comment: Can you post part of the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load and filter the file when the bot starts, then call `choice` on that list

```
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot("!")

with open('FullLogs.txt',encoding='ANSI') as f:
    links = [line for line in f if 'https://' in line]

@client.command(aliases=["randfile","randvideo","randlink"])
async def randimage(ctx):
    linetosend = random.choice(links)
    if 'discordapp' in linetosend or 'twitter' in linetosend:
            linetosend= linetosend.replace("]","").replace("'","").replace(">","")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('<:ohgod:710655825261363240>')
    await ctx.send(f"{linetosend}")
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but had to change the bottom section that says `await ctx.send(f"{newlinetosend}")` to `await ctx.send(f"{linetosend}")` to match your changes